# INSERT INTO selecting wrong column

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one a temp table I've dumped data into from an Excel spreadsheet and the other the SQL table I'd like to use for our website. I'd like to transfer over the values for the `PensgcException` column in the temp table into `OriginalPensgcException` in the primary, SQL table. However, each time I run my statement I get the following error, which seems to suggest the way I've written my query it's trying to move the `Pensgc` column from one table to another.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Pensgc', table 'AgentResourcesU01.dbo.PENSGC'; 
>       column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

**PENSGCs$** (temp table)

```
PENSGC                      nvarchar(255) null
PensgcException             nvarchar(255) null
```

**PENSGC**

```
Pensgc                  PK char(3) not null
OriginalPensgcException FK int     null
```

**T-SQL**

```
INSERT INTO PENSGC (OriginalPensgcException)
SELECT PensgcException
FROM PENSGCs$ t
INNER JOIN PENSGC p ON t.PENSGC = p.Pensgc
WHERE p.Pensgc = t.PENSGC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want an `update`, not an `insert`.  `insert` puts new rows into the table.  `update` changes the value in a row.  This may do what you want:

```
UPDATE p
    set OriginalPensgcException = t.PensgcException
FROM PENSGCs$ t INNER JOIN
     PENSGC p
     ON t.PENSGC = p.Pensgc;
```