# Insert into is populating wrong column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure what I'm missing. If I run this script:

```
    insert into [myDB].[dbo].[Courses] (SessionDetails, SessionStartDate, [SessionEndDate])   select s.SessionDetails, s.SessionStartDate, s.SessionEndDate
  from [myDB].[dbo].[Courses] c inner join [myDB].[dbo].[CourseSessions] s on c.CourseID = s.CourseID
```

It is trying to insert into the first column it finds in the `[myDB].[dbo].[Courses]` table which is `DefaultPrice` even if I'm specifying the column name in the script.
The desired behavior is that it populates the columns I'm specifying within the parenthesis(SessionDetails, SessionStartDate and [SessionEndDate])

Comment: Can you replicate this problem in https://dbfiddle.uk ?  Because I can't replicate your problem any where.

Comment: Do you have an INSTEAD OF trigger on dbo.Courses?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning no triggers in the dbo.Courses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post helped a lot: [INSERT INTO selecting wrong column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765226/insert-into-selecting-wrong-column)

I ended up using `update-set` syntax instead of `insert into`.